Curve Color Viewport Display settings. How can I see the individual chosen color in the viewport?
I'm trying to see the colors I have set in Curve objects Viewport Display settings.
I can set them to any color here but I cannot see where to make this show in the viewport shading options.
There is a global default wire color setting for making them all the same color in
Edit > Preferences > Themes > 3d Viewport > Wire, but this is not helpful to me as I have thousands of curves which I need to make distinguishable by color groups.
The object Viewport Display Color settings seems to work only for geometry and not for curve.
Is this a deliberate limitation, or am I missing a way of switching on the curve object color settings on the viewport?

What Labcat says is true, though I don't think it is so much a deliberate choice, probably just overlooked, or simply a limitation of the current rendering system.
Here is a possible hacky workaround.

Since object color properties only seems to be respected for mesh objects, lets turn our curves into "meshes", non destructively.
On all your curve objects add an Edge Split modifier. On a bare bezier curve (without bevels) this changes nothing visually, but on the purely technical side, it makes what is being drawn in the viewport virtually a mesh object, rather than a curve, despite looking the same.
From the Viewport Shading popover make sure Wire Color is set to By object.
Adjust curve object color as desired. This should display in Wireframe viewport shading mode only. To make it also visible in Solid mode, make sure to turn on Wireframe in all the curve objects Viewport Properties.


Wait, line-only mesh objects CAN have custom colors?

Yes, this is a deliberate / known limitation. Object color is only rendered onto faces. However, I do agree that being able to set colors for individual objects’ edges could be very useful. I recommend you make a feature request for this to be an additional object color setting. You can make such a request on the Right Click Select community.
